# How do compressible fluids behave near a sink?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Imagine there is a large spherical tank of a fluid floating in space.  There is a small pipe from the outside to the inside that opens in the center of the spherical tank and lets fluid out *at a constant rate*.

How does this fluid behave?

Specifically, what is the velocity of the fluid as a function of radius?

For an incompressible fluid I conjecture that the velocity would be proportional to $1/r^2$.

However, what about a compressible fluid?  Would the density increase or decrease near the sink?  What would it say about the fluid if the density increased?  What would it say about the fluid if the velocity was proportional to $\sqrt{1/r}$?

Assume constant pressure on the outer boundary of the fluid. (Infinitely large tank; collapsible tank; fluid replaced from the outside, whatever)

Comment: What kind of fluid? Air, water, oil? What pressure is outside the tank? Is gravity present?

Comment: @JánLalinský No gravity is present.  I believe (could be wrong) the pressure outside won't matter except for the vacuum created on the pipe, which might as well be the source of the fluid ejection.  As far as the material, let's say I don't really know, but I'm trying to find out.  How would each of those materials behave differently in this situation?

Comment: A real compressible medium like a gas will have fully developed turbulence long before there is sizable compression, so in a sense physics bypasses the simple solution that you are looking for. As soon as you have compression, the assumptions of isothermal flow are severely violated, too, so one has to calculate everything with the equations of fluid mechanics and thermodynamics combined, that, however, is an internally inconsistent set because thermodynamics needs near equilibrium and fluid dynamics is very far from it... so you are left with kludges like in the physics of supersonic flow.

Comment: @CuriousOne Does it help to declare it a compressible liquid?

Comment: You have a spherical reservoir, in 0G, with a sink at the center. Velocity depends on the volume flow rate out of the sink, and you don't say anything about that. As long as the velocity is sufficiently below the speed of sound in the fluid, you can treat the fluid as incompressible. Keep in mind you're going to get a vortex around the sink, because the angular momentum of the fluid will almost certainly be > 0.

Comment: @aepryus: Air is compressible. When you compress it, it heats up, like every other gas. So now you have to deal with an internal thermodynamic degree of freedom, which is not part of fluid mechanics. Since your compression depends on the location, there will be a temperature gradient... oops... now you need a theory that can deal with that (thermodynamics can't), so you throw some sort of transport theory into the mix... can you see how messy things get?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Thanks for pointing that out.  An important aspect of this problem is that the flow out of the reservoir is constant.  I'll adjust the question.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Reminding me about the vortex was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer this generally. Water expelled to vacuum will boil and part will evaporate, part will freeze. The ice may block the pipe, it may not. If there is high enough pressure outside the tank (atmosphere), the resulting motion of the water will depend on the pressure difference. As soon as some water gets out, pressure inside will decrease and the flow may stop.

Comment: I'm sorry for my ambiguous question.  I am interested in the fluid inside the tank not the fluid outside.  Assuming constant pressure on the outer edge of the fluid (infinite tank, collapsible tank or fluid replaced somehow).